# Como traduzir a expressão "Swarm and stick"?

Tags: expressões, tradução-inglês, tradução, expressões-equivalentes

Eu tenho a seguinte expressão:

"Relentless Pursuit of the Football. Swarm and Stick."

Nesse contexto, que envolve futebol americano, como ficaria no português essa expressão?

Comment: O que significa essa expressão?

Comment: Concordo com o @ANeves que é primeiro preciso saber bem o que significa «swarm and stick» neste contexto, para depois então tentarmos encontrar uma expressão equivalente em português. Talvez valesse a pena perguntar no [Sports SE](http://sports.stackexchange.com/), [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions) ou no [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: Lucas, postei uma [pergunta sobre *swarm and stick* no Sports SE](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14108/what-does-swarm-and-stick-mean-in-american-football) e tenho uma resposta. Podes incluir a informação na tua pergunta.

Comment: Já dei uma resposta e  ninguém disse nada. Vocês não topam saber o sentido?

Comment: examear ou fazer enxame e colar [ao jogador que leva a bola]. Já é a segunda vez que respondo. Eu vejo futebol americano todo o tempo. Alguém aqui assiste aos jogos de futebol americano?? Ou é só pergunta para machista?

Answer (score 1):

Tradução completa:

**Eterna meta do futebol americano: coesão e persistência.**

Traduções individuais (palavra por palavra. Só não traduzi a preposição *of* e o artigo *the*):

- Relentless = incansável, eterno, infindável, interminável...
- Pursuit = perseguição, meta, objetivo, busca...
- Football = futebol americano (no contexto indicado pelo autor da
  pergunta).
- Swarm = em sentido literal, corresponde ao substantivo *enxame* (de abelhas, por exemplo) ou ao verbo *enxamear* (mover-se como um enxame, movimentar-se em grupo, todos os elementos do grupo deslocam-se juntos, de maneira coordenada, de modo coeso).

  Já no sentido figurado, que é o adotado na frase que foi transcrita pelo autor da pergunta, a palavra *swarm* remete à noção de uma **atuação em grupo** (conjunta) e **de maneira organizada, coordenada, coesa**. Em outras palavras, refere-se ao contexto em que um conjunto de indivíduos (um grupo, um time, uma equipe, uma coletividade etc.) executa, de maneira coesa, uma ação coordenada que converge (e/ou que faz tal grupo/time/equipe/coletividade etc. convergir) para um objetivo comum a todos esses indivíduos, a todo esse grupo/time, a toda essa equipe/coletividade etc.

  No contexto do futebol americano, tal atuação em prol de um objetivo comum é a ação coordenada (de ataque, de defesa etc.) do time inteiro de futebol americano contra qualquer time adversário de futebol americano.
- Stick = grudar, colar, aderir, continuar, manter, permanecer, teimar, obstinar, persistir, perseverar...

Em outras palavras: na frase apresentada, as palavras *swarm* e *stick* foram usadas em sentido figurado, de modo a representar o time de futebol americano como sendo um **persistente enxame de jogadores**, ou seja, um grupo coeso de indivíduos que possuem o mesmo objetivo. Por isto, esses indivíduos movimentam-se de maneira coesa, coordenada, "enxameada", e fazem isso (agem assim) o tempo todo, de modo determinado, persistente, incansável etc. ao longo de toda e cada uma das partidas de futebol.

Em síntese, o que a frase está afirmando é que, no futebol americano, o time tem de ser coeso e não abandonar essa coesão em absolutamente momento nenhum. A chave para o sucesso consiste, portanto, em o time de futebol americano persistentemente manter-se unido, coeso, sempre se movimentar de maneira coordenada, jamais deixar de ser e agir assim.

Answer (score 1):

Swarm é uma ação pela qual todos os jogadores de certa forma vão se juntando na direção da bola.

Stick é ficar com ou encima do jogador que tem a bola até conseguir o controlo dela. Ou seja, ficar "colado" ao jogador. Formar enxame ou examear e colar

[desenho de uma táctica de "enxame" no futebol americano](http://www.y-coach.com/CD/swarm.gif)

> [swarm drill](http://www.y-coach.com/CD/Youth_Flag_Football_-_Swarm_Drill.htm)